# IOS 11.3 PWA clears login token on startup

Tags: ios, token, progressive-web-apps, ios11.3

Unfortunately it seems IOS 11.3 progressive web apps start completely fresh every time its opened from the home screen. Because of this the user is having to login each time the app is opened, has anyone found a workaround to retain login credentials between app launches ?